# Android: How do I create an object of a database admin class and then use it?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am working on an Android project where I have a central database for the application and it is accessed/ input into from different activities within the same app. I am still a bit of a noob when it comes to Android and have followed various tutorials, but only to get myself slightly stuck :/

**The problem I am having is this**, if the code posted below is my "base" class that is the one I will be using via objects and methods to access, how do I create an object with the correct parameters so as to make it work?

I try to create an object of the DatabaseAdmin class in a different class with the following syntax:
DatabaseAdmin db = new DatabaseAdmin();
But it is saying I need to add the parameter, context. 
When I input the parameter as:
DatabaseAdmin db = new DatabaseAdmin(getApplicationContext());
The app keeps force closing with multiple errors, so I am thinking this is not the solution.

Ideas? How do I create an object that will have access to this class with all of the respective methods available to it and afterwards, do I need to do anything abnormal to utilize/ call it?

(PS, apologies if I included too much code, tried to trim it down, not sure if something was important that might be a clue. If it is too much code, please let me know and I will trim it further)

Here is my code:

```
    //imports Cropped for space saving
    //This class manages the database for the entire application

    public class DatabaseAdmin extends Activity
    {
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
    Context ctx;

    //Create an object of the SQLite database which we can use to open and close it
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    //SQL Variables
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_AT_RISK = "at_risk";
    public static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    public static final String COMMA = ",";

    //String to create the database
    public static final String SQL_CREATE_DATABASE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + 
            TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            COLUMN_NAME_AT_RISK + " REAL 1417" 
            " )";

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "RSRToolbox.db";

    public DatabaseAdmin(Context ctx) {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    }

    //DatabaseHelper
    private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        //Constructor for DatabaseHelper
        public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //Creates database
            try {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_DATABASE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST commissions");
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }

    //Method to open the database
    public DatabaseAdmin openDB(){
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //Method for closing the database
    public void closeDB(){
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    //Method to insert data into the database
    public long InsertData(String column_name, String value){

        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(column_name, value);
        return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
    }

    public Cursor getData(String[] column_name){

        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, column_name, null, null, null, null, null);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Remove this: `extends Activity`. It doesn't.

Comment: I shall do that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the singleton model:

Your App class (register in manifest) :

```
class MyApp extends Application {
private static MyApp mInstance;

void onCreate() {
   mInstance = this;
}

public Context context() { return mInstance.getApplicationContext(); }

}
```

Your database class:

```
public MyDatabase {

public final MyDatabase INSTANCE = new MyDatabase();

private DbHelper mHelper;

public Cursor someMyQuery() {
    return mHelper.query(...);
}

private MyDatabase() {
    mHelper = new DbHelper(MyApp.context());
    ...
}

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   onCreate() {...}
   onUpdate() {...}
}

}
```

Then from anywhere to access your databases:

```
MyDatabase.INSTANCE.someMyQuery();
```